# File exists but not visible in [folder]/AllItems.apsx when uploading to SharePoint via Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, http-put

I am tasked with uploading a file to SharePoint via Java. My upload is working properly. I am using HTTP PUT:

```
HttpPut("http://[server]/[site]/[folder]/[filename]")
```

And when I visit the aforementioned link: http://[server]/[site]/[folder]/[filename] the file downloads in my browser. However, when I visit: http://[server]/[site]/[folder]/ I get the message:

> There are no files in the view "All Documents"

I suspect this is something to do with SharePoint conventions and I am very new to SharePoint. I only have read access to the site so it may be difficult to diagnose some issues - just thought someone out there might have encountered this before.

~ Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I should have put this in the original question, but I am so new to SharePoint I didn't think of it.

The trailing [folder] was actually '/Forms/'. I guess this is a SharePoint caveat in which the file is present when uploading here but only back-end accessible via SharePoint designer.

I removed /Forms/ from the end of my upload URL and the file appeared in the same location, and is now visible.

**Note to anyone trying to upload to SharePoint:** If your link ends in [/Forms/], just remove that from the end of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint, views are created by default when a library is created.
However if the filters are added to this view you might not see the contents of the library.

Check with your Sharepoint site administrator if there are any filters on the "Allitems" view.